# How to remove a doskey macro?

Tags: windows, doskey

I have created a doskey macro I want to remove. 
How do I delete it? 
How can I see all the macros I have created?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check out the [doskey documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/doskey):

> Displays doskey macros for all executables

```
doskey /macros:all
```

> To delete a macro called *vlist*, type:

```
doskey vlist =
```

Comment: when I define a doskey in the shell, if I close it the doskey is automatically removed. Is this its normal functionality or there is some other problem?

Comment: @Sajuuk Check out https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrewarnottms/2007/07/09/getting-doskey-macros-to-work-in-powershell/